# Unpacking list items from a dictionary & writing to a CSV file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains a list of 4 items per key.
I'm trying to write each individual list item to a Var column in a CSV file, but I haven't been having much luck.

```
try:
    f = open('numbers2.csv', 'wt')
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerow(('Var1', "Var2", 'Var3', "Var4",))
    for x in exchangeDict2.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(x)
```

This code will print the key in one column, and the list in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to iterate over dictionary values, use `itervalues()`:

```
for value in exchangeDict2.itervalues():
    writer.writerow(value)
```

Also, use `with` context manager while working with files (it handles `close()` for you):

```
with open('numbers2.csv', 'wt') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerow(('Var1', "Var2", 'Var3', "Var4",))
    for value in exchangeDict2.itervalues():
        writer.writerow(value)
```

Comment: Thank you, such a simple fix makes me feel silly, but at least I'll remember it for next time!